# Unobvious behavior when adding a column to pgfplots table

Tags: pgfplots, errors, pgfplotstable, compilation-error

I've noticed a peculiarity in `pgfplots/table` package. I don't know if it's a bug or a feature.

Error code

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table[x=X,
        y={create col/expr={\thisrow{X}^2}}] {
        X Y
        1 1
        2 2
        3 3
        4 4
        5 5
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>  .../table/create on use/create col/expr={\thisrow
> {X}^2}/.@cmd
> l.16         };

When I encountered this error, I couldn't understand for a long time what its cause was.

This kind of code works:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread {
        X Y
        1 1
        2 2
        3 3
        4 4
        5 5
        }\data
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table[x=X,
        y={create col/expr={\thisrow{X}^2}}] \data;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That is, if I announce the table at the beginning, there is no error.

This one works too:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table[x=X,
        create on use/Z/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{X}^2}}, 
        y=Z] {
        X Y
        1 1
        2 2
        3 3
        4 4
        5 5
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the last example, we add a column via a style. Strangely, this is done via a style, although it has nothing to do with styles.

Is there some inconsistency in the implementation itself here? Why doesn't the first example work, giving an unobvious error?

Comment: `\addplot table [x=X, y expr={\thisrow{X}^2}]` also woks.

Comment: With [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys), the key-value system used by `pgfplot`, the handler `/.style` is a way to set other keys. It isn't specific to formatting. I think that with `create on use` the y values are computed after the table has been read, when `\thisrow` is defined.

Comment: Always set the `compat` level when using PGFPlots.

Answer (score 1):

PGFPlots needs to read the whole table to create new columns:

`read completely`

> This key has just one purpose, namely to create postprocessing columns
> on the fly and to plot those columns afterwards.

The default is to only read the table into memory if there is a `create on use`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[read completely, x=X, y={create col/expr={\thisrow{X}^2}}] {
X Y
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with parabola]

A better method is of cause to use `\addplot table [x=X, y expr={\thisrow{X}^2}]`